# Spring Rest - Uso de vários Services e Repositories

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

Estou com uma dúvida sobre a melhor forma de implementar alguns serviços com o **Spring Rest**, mas não consegui encontrar material para esse caso:

Digamos que eu tenha um serviço para fazer lançamentos (*LancamentoService*). Esse serviço faz o lançamento, atualiza o saldo e cobra tarifa. Logo, nele tenho injetado os repositories *LancamentoRepository*, *SaldoRepository* e *TarifaRepository*.

Além desse serviço, também teria serviços para fazer saque, transferência, etc, e todos esses precisariam fazer um lançamento, além de outras coisas. Para fazer isso eu estou injetando o *LancamentoService* dentro de cada um desses sevices.

Porém, mesmo que eu chame um serviço no *SaqueService*, por exemplo, que não precisaria fazer lançamentos, o L*ancamentoService* é “carregado”, junto com todos os seus repositories.

Isso é assim mesmo? Se alguém tiver uma prática melhor ou algum material de referência agradeço bastante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logo no início da aplicação, o Spring já varre suas classes em busca de *beans* para serem gerenciados por ele. Isso significa que mesmo em classes nas quais seu programa sequer passou ainda, os *beans* dela já estão, em teoria, instanciados e gerenciados, prontos para uso. Em outras palavras, qualquer *bean* injetado em sua classe, mesmo que não em uso, estará previamente instanciado. É um pequeno preço a se pagar pela enorme facilidade que a [inversão de controle](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invers%C3%A3o_de_controle) proporciona no desenvolvimento.

Quanto à sua arquitetura, eu criaria um serviço para cada ação do lançamento (`TarifaService`, `SaldoService` etc.), injetaria dentro de cada um deles seu respectivo `Repository` e, finalmente, na classe `LancamentoService`, injetaria esses serviços criados. Isso facilita a você a centralização de regras de negócio que eventualmente precisem ser aplicadas à tarifa, por exemplo, e também se conforma às melhores práticas, que dizem que regras de negócio devem ser tratadas na camada de serviço e não na camada DAO (repositórios).

Comment: Entendi, então eu não estava muito longe do ideal. Aproveitando então: o uso de um Repository genérico traria algum benefício de performance?

Comment: Não é *repository* genérico. Hoje, seguindo seu exemplo, você injeta direto na classe `LancamentoService` os *repositories* das ações que um lançamento pode ter. Isso não é uma boa ideia. O melhor é que cada um desses *repositories* tenha seu próprio serviço (ou seja, por exemplo, você criaria um `SaldoService` e, dentro dele sim injetaria o `SaldoRepository`, criaria um método público, por ex.: calcularSaldo(), e, na classe `LancamentoService`, você injeta esse `SaldoService` (e não o `SaldoRepository`, como você citou no seu exemplo) recém-criado e chama o método `calcularSaldo()`.

Comment: Beleza. Muito obrigado!